# How to add _sql_constraints to check char field lenght in odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have a fields.Char attribute “identification_id”, That field must have  11 characters. How can I add a _sql_constraints to check the length of that field and ensure it should be 11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Check Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html) with [length](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-string.html) function

```
_sql_constraints = {
    ('check_name', 'check(length(name)>10)', 'name must be at least 11 characters')
}
```

***Edit:***

The constraint will not be added if you have already a record that did not satisfy it:

```
ERROR demo odoo.sql_db: bad query: ALTER TABLE "hr_employee" ADD CONSTRAINT "hr_employee_check_name" check(length(name)>10)
ERROR: ERROR:  The verification constraint "hr_employee_check_name" is broken by a line
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it. I had to make sure that there was not any record with any other lenght different from 11